# QuarkusTest ignores custom Maven user settings file

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

Running a `QuarkusTest` fails, when Maven settings are set in a user settings file (i.e. `~/.m2/settings-custom.xml` as opposed to a more standard scenario `~/.m2/settings.xml`).

This is also the case when a `.mvn/maven.config` file with a reference to the settings file is defined at project level with contents as follows: `-s /Users/johndoe/.m2/settings-custom.xml`.

Also, IntelliJ has a setting, which allows setting custom Maven settings files:

[image]

That setting does not seem to work either.

Any ideas?

If I replace `settings.xml` with the contents of `settings-custom.xml`, everything works as expected.

Comment: For what purpose is `settings-custom.xml` needed? Why do you need something like this in a test?

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Comment: The `settings-custom.xml` is not intended for tests. I need a few different Maven settings files on my machine, in one project one settings file, in another project another one.

I'm running the tests directly from Maven, i.e. `mvn verify`, or directly in the IDE.